# Apache Nutch doesn't index rss feed properly

Tags: solr, rss, feed, nutch

I've been trying indexing RSS pages on Solr using "feed" as parser (and not tika.
In theory for each RSS's item, one document should be created in Solr. And it is created! But only temporarily. 
In fact once the indexing finished successfully, the cleaning job deletes all the RSS items.

My guess is that doesn't find the url of the RSS's item in the crawlDB, and therefore it deletes them from Solr during the cleanjob. Could it be right?

EDIT:
I have noticed that all the entries have the same "signature" because the fetcher decided so. Therefore the dedup mark them as duplicates and the cleaner clean them.

I'm trying to modify this from happening, but I don't understand why it has been configured in such a way.

Answer (score 1):

The feed plugin in Nutch generates multiple documents from the feed file without fetching the URLs listed there. My guess is that it assigns the same signature as the feed page to all the subdocuments which as you pointed out results in them being deduplicated.

This is should not happen and is clearly a bug. Could you please open a JIRA issue for it?

You could remove the deduplication step from the crawl script so that your documents are preserved in the index.

Alternatively you could write a modified version of the plugin which simply extracts the outlinks from the feed and lets Nutch fetch the subdocuments as usual. This way each doc will get its own signature and the deduplication will make sense.

Another reason why you would prefer that is that the feed entry might not contain the entire text / metadata of the subdocument.

Funnily enough, I've just added a resource for parsing feeds in [StormCrawler](https://github.com/DigitalPebble/storm-crawler/pull/291), unlike the one in Nutch it simply detects outlinks and fetches them later on.

Comment: Thanks, I'll open a jira issue and check out StormCrawler too

Comment: No problems. Feel free to mark my answer as useful and/or your problem resolved